Failed to download and view the file from the local path (ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)
I deployed CSP policies to my system and then encountered an error when trying to view a PDF file from the local path. Before adding the CSP policies, this issue did not occur. This problem appears in Edge and Chrome but not in Firefox. A workaround is to add the Adobe Acrobat extension. Is there any way to amend the program to allow viewing the file?
Error Occurred
My CSP program:
List<String> cspPolicies = new ArrayList<String>();
String originLocationRef = "'self'";

cspPolicies.add("default-src 'self'");
cspPolicies.add("script-src " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'");
cspPolicies.add("object-src " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline'");
cspPolicies.add("style-src " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline'");
cspPolicies.add("img-src " + originLocationRef + " data:");
cspPolicies.add("form-action " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline'");
if (APP_USE_AUDIOS_OR_VIDEOS) {
    cspPolicies.add("media-src " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline'");
}

if (APP_USE_WEBFONTS) {
    cspPolicies.add("font-src " + originLocationRef + " 'unsafe-inline'");
}

cspPolicies.add("connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'");
this.policies = cspPolicies.toString().replaceAll("(\\[|\\])", "").replaceAll(",", ";").trim();

if (isFrame) {
    policiesBuffer.append(";").append("frame-src 'self';sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-downloads");
    if (INCLUDE_MOZILLA_CSP_DIRECTIVES) {
        policiesBuffer.append(";").append("frame-ancestors 'self'");
    }
}

I have try to amend:
policiesBuffer.append(";").append("frame-src 'self';sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-downloads");

by adding sandbox value like allow-modals, allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox, allow-top-navigation-to-custom-protocols but the error still occurred.

Looks like an old issue for Chromium. Though they delivered a fix later, the problem has recently reappeared somehow.
Some workarounds you can try now:

Drop the sandbox CSP attribute for PDFs.
Open PDFs via Ctrl + Left click to open them in a new tab. Here's a good code example if you choose this workaround.

For the fix, please create an issue at https://issues.chromium.org/ to let Dev Team know about it.
